# How to replace the repeating part string with regex?

Tags: regex, django

I have the following urls with format written in django:

```
{% url 'wap:client:goods_category' %}
```

And I want to replace them into:

```
/wap/client/goods-category.html
```

I'm using jetbrains IDE, and want to replace them with regex.

So I wrote the following pattern:

```
\{% url '([^']+):([^']+):([^']+)' %\}
```

Repace to:

```
/$1/$2/$3.html
```

#### Problem:

This helps, but the underscore is not able to be replaced to a dash sign.

There may be zero or more underscore in the page name.

So also tried:

```
\{% url '([^']+):([^']+):([^'\_]+\_)*([^']+)' %\}
```

This do match all the page name segments, but I cannot know how many segments are matched.

---

A solultion? Please help!

Comment: since jetbrains is built in java, i'd look for a java regex online checker (perhaps this one: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to help you determine what is being matched, in what group, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callable in the `repl` argument of `re.sub()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> def to_slashes(s):
...     return s.replace(':', '/').replace('_', '-') + '.html'
... 
>>> url = "{% url 'wap:client:goods_category' %}"
>>> re.sub("{% url '([^']+)' %}", lambda x: to_slashes(x.group(1)), url)
'wap/client/goods-category.html'
>>> url = "{% url 'wap:client:goods:goods_category' %}"
>>> re.sub("{% url '([^']+)' %}", lambda x: to_slashes(x.group(1)), url)
'wap/client/goods/goods-category.html'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is a pure replacement pattern, which I can use in the Jetbrains IDE, is there any way?